# Php HTML: Table not aligned properly

Tags: php, html-table

I have this problem

[image]

the header and the data is not aligned properly.

and this is the

```html
<iframe src="https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/ceh9cPb1" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
```

how can I fix it? thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: near `"<td>". $row["mop"] ."<td>"`  and `<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success pull-right">Print</button><td>` you have not close `</td>` just close it , it should work.

Comment: @Swati didn't work

Comment: @Swati actually it works :D THANKS!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question (in text form and properly formatted, or as an executable code snippet in cases where that makes sense), and not just dumped on an external site.